# How to apply a awk command to a certain number of files?

Tags: linux, awk

I've X numbers of files and I've this command :

```
awk ' /'$awk_value'/ {split(FILENAME,a,"-");print a[2]"-"a[3]"-"a[4]","$2","$3}' /xxx/xxx/all_my_files > /xxx/xxx/xxx/TEST.txt
```

But for exemple, if I have 120 files... How Can I apply this command to only the seven last files ?

Comment: We seem to have picked up a large number of new users that lack the common decency to leave a comment when they downvote, much less go out of their way to provide a helpful suggestion on how the question can be made better...

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean my "last". From an alphabetic ordering by file name? Or the newest files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tail` command, then use `xargs` to use the output as the argument list.

```
ls /xxx/xxx/my_files*.txt | tail -7 | 
    xargs awk -v awk_value="$awk_value" '$0 ~ awk_value {split(FILENAME,a,"-");print a[2]"-"a[3]"-"a[4]","$2","$3}' > /xxx/xxx/xxx/TEST.txt
```

This assumes that the "last 7" is based on an order that the `ls` command can produce (e.g. order by filename, order by modification time).

Notice also the use of the `-v` option to turn a shell variable into an `awk` variable, rather than your method of concatenating it (which wouldn't work if `$awk_value` contains whitespace -- you should always double-quote variables to protect against this).

Comment: The output of ls is designed for human consumption, not programmatic

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin well this command would fail if a filename contains a newline for example

Comment: @EricRenouf - while those should generally be protected against, they are more corner cases (or old Mac filenames) and are worth of a comment and suggestion, but not a downvote without more. 99% of shell answer on SO would fail in that regard. Many people will go their entire computing lifetime without encountering filenames containing embedded newline characters. The alternative would be `find .. -print0` to `xargs -0` to `tail`, if you are protecting against them.

Comment: Maybe also highlight how passing in a variable with `-v` is vastly more robust than interpolating an (unquoted!) value smack dab into the source.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I do not have  suggestion on what would be the appropriate, because the asker didn't provide enough information. Your suggestion of  find & xargs doesn't really work since there is no way to limit the number of used arguments from xargs (AFAIK).  As for the "99% of shell answer on SO would fail in that regard", this is the one I've looked on, if I see another I will probably do the same.

Comment: You could put them in an array and take the last 7 with `"${arr[@]: -7}"`

Comment: @Sorin In general I wouldn't recommend code like this, but I can't think of any other way to do "last 7" in the shell. `ls` is the only standard shell utility that sorts files by various criteria.

Comment: @Barmar sort is one option and has -z, find can be used to restrict based on time and no sort is necessary, tail has -z and so on.... But without knowing what last 7 means, you can't know. There are quite a lot of options that do not require ls. However, the main issue is answering a incomplete question, just for the sake of answering.

Comment: My main intent was to show that whatever you use to produce the list of files, you can pipe it to `tail -n 7` to get the last 7, and then feed that to `xargs`.